# Const definition in method and memory use

Tags: c#, memory-management, constants, keyword

I'm making a little map (`Dictionary<string, someEnum>`, basically) and am wondering where to put the definition of this map. It'll only be used in this one method, and so it seems a little silly to pollute the namespace of the class with a private Dictionary and populate that dict in the constructor. What I'd rather do is have the definition be at the place of use, but flagged in such a way as to tell the compiler not to trash it when the method's returned. I suspect that in normal use-cases, this method will be called thousands of times per hour, so minimizing the overhead would be nice.

So my question is: Is there a keyword in C#, maybe `const`, that will have this effect, and if not, what's the best practice here?

Comment: Unless you're having performance issues, don't bother. `const` should act as you expect, but even so, you're wasting time. Getting answers here is slower than fixing them when needed.

Comment: It's sort of an academic/aesthetic consideration, I understand, but one still wonders. Thanks for the input.

Comment: "Pollute the namespace of the class" - I'm not sure I understand that. If it's private, it won't be externally visible. Seems like taking things to the extreme. I would add it as a `private static readonly` dictionary and use the literal method of defining it.

Comment: You can't have a const dictionary.